# Would it be unbalanced to allow non-warforged to have armblades if they also have a prosthetic limb?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, house-rules, eberron

I bought the D&D 5e book Eberron Rising From The Last War. I saw there were magic items in it, and in particular prosthetic limbs. That reminded me of a prestige class, the renegade mastermaker (Magic of Eberron), in D&D 3.5, the point of which was to (sort of) become a warforged.

Then I saw that armblades (and similar magic items) are only for warforged, my idea was crushed.

The advantage of prosthetic limbs is that they are cheaper than a regeneration spell, but they require you to be attuned (which is, for me, a big cost). Why not make it a little bit better by saying that it allows you to attune to armblades, (and similar magic items) even if you are not a warforged?

Would that be unbalanced? If so, what did I miss?

Comment: For clarity, are these homebrewed prosthetics precisely *duplicating* the armblades (and similar) that Warforged get, for anyone that cares to purchase/craft one?

Comment: @Upper_Case-StopHarmingMonica No, the prosthetics don't have the effect of an armblade. It just hollow you to attune to one like if you were a warforged

Comment: If you have a "guess" as to the answer (i.e. your own assessment of whether such a house-rule would be balanced), that would probably be better as an answer than in the question, especially if you have reasoning to back up that guess (rather than just an unsubstantiated feeling), which you do seem to have. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that is not so unbalanced (or unbalanced in the "it's still weak" way).

Having the prosthetic limb allowing to use an armblade (or similar magic items) cost you 2 attunements instead of one (for me it's a lot), and make the "you can bypass the warforged requirement" somehow weak (but less weak that "you just replace your arm").

It make prosthetic limb have an interest, in a similar way of the 3.5 prestige class renegade mastermaker (Magic of Eberron), that have this feature at level 1 (level 4 of the PC) with other features and for the only cost of your level, and meeting the requirement, which is not a big deal if it's your character concept anyway.

Even if 5e and 3.5 are different, they share a lot of similarities that help to guess if something is balanced or not.